# Mapping custom enum classes with Fluent Nhibernate

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, enums, nhibernate-mapping

Reading [some](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2008/08/12/enumeration-classes.aspx) [posts](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2008/08/26/strategies-and-discriminators-in-nhibernate.aspx) from Jimmy Boggard and wondering - how exactly is it possible to map those beasts with fluent nhibernate?

How mapping would look like for this?

```
public class EmployeeType : Enumeration{
    public static readonly EmployeeType 
     Manager = new EmployeeType(0, "Manager"),
     Servant = new EmployeeType(1, "Servant"),
     AssistantToTheRegionalManager = new EmployeeType
       (2, "Assistant to the Regional Manager");

    private EmployeeType() { }
    private EmployeeType(int value, string displayName) : 
        base(value, displayName) { }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah... it was easy. In CodeCampServer - there's a generic EnumerationType class. Idea is simple - we just need to wrap our domain model enumeration value object with EnumerationType in order to map it as integer (or anything else if necessary).

Comment: +1 thanks, and for anyone who wants it you can find it here: http://code.google.com/p/codecampserver/source/browse/trunk/src/Infrastructure/EnumerationType.cs

Comment: This link is invalid. http://code.google.com/p/codecampserver/source/browse/trunk/src/Infrastructure.NHibernate/DataAccess/EnumerationType.cs?spec=svn1063&r=1063

Comment: Thanks for fixing it. They changed project structure a bit.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create derive from IUserType and specify how to store an retrieve the information from a specific column on the database, serializing and deserializing the enumeration.

Check [this article](http://intellect.dk/post/Implementing-custom-types-in-nHibernate.aspx) for a simple explanation of the basics of IUserType.