# FluentNHibernate: how to access field which has datatype different to property

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a database with a field 'LS_GENDER' which stores genders as 'M' or 'F'.

My application uses an enumeration called Gender to work with genders.

My entity has the following field and property:

```
private string _gender;

public Gender Gender { get { return GetGenderFromString(_gender); } };

private Gender GetGenderFromString(string strGender)
{
  switch (strGender.ToLower())
  {
    case "f":
      return Gender.Female;
    case "m":
      return Gender.Male;
    default:
      return Gender.Unknown;
  }
}
```

How do I map this with FluentNHibernate? I am trying to use field access (as shown below):

```
Map(x => x.Gender).Column("LS_GENDER").Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore);
```

but I'm getting the error 'Can't parse F as Gender'. I think NHibernate is getting confused because the property and field are not of the same type.

How should I map this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You map a private field using [reveal](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Fluent_mapping_private_properties):

```
Map(Reveal.Member<ClassType>("_gender")).Column("LS_GENDER");
```

But that doesn't resolve your LINQ problem because now NHibernate doesn't know about the Gender property. To resolve both issues I would use a custom user type that implements IUserType.

Comment: I solved this using IUsertype. Aim Kai also talked about IUserType, but less directly.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are mapping a database string value (M,F,U) to an enumeration.

The answer to this question may help you map enumerations to string values.

[How do you map an enum as an int value with fluent NHibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439003/how-do-you-map-an-enum-as-an-int-value-with-fluent-nhibernate)
[Mapping custom enum classes with Fluent Nhibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593773/mapping-custom-enum-classes-with-fluent-nhibernate)

You could use a custom type to map the strings (M,F,U) to the enumeration you've got.

On your enumeration class using a custom attribute to specify its string value. The following article may help you how to do this.

http://david.gardiner.net.au/2007/11/using-enum-types-with-nhibernate.html

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I don't think the first link is really relevant. The second link is a potential solution, but involves invasive coding outside my NHibernate implementation - e.g. adding custom attributes to the Gender enumeration. I should be able to solve this within NHibernate itself. I'm currently using a custom IPropertyAccessor, but I don't seem to be able to get it to work...

Answer (score 0):

To my considerable astonishment, this mapping worked:

```
Map(x => x.Gender).Column("LS_GENDER").Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore).CustomType(typeof (string));
```

So the mapping says 'access the field directly and treat it as a string, even though the corresponding property is of type Gender'.

Comment: Ah, but then I can't do Linq queries on the Gender. I get: Type mismatch in NHibernate.Criterion.SimpleExpression: Deceased.Gender expected type System.String, actual type Kctc.Gender

Comment: Maybe provide your own custom type?